# UIVideoEditorController allwas change the video resolution

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uivideoeditorcontroller

I am trying to trim video using UIVideoEditorController. After trimming or saving, using UIVideoEditorController lost my video resolution. I used `UIImagePickerController` to taking video with set resolution to `UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame1280x720` and set the url path to UIVideoEditorController with property videoQuality to (iPhone 5) `UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame1280x720`. That same efect when I use AVFoudation framework to capture video. Why I lost resolution?
My code:

```
  if ([UIVideoEditorController canEditVideoAtPath:self.videoPath]) {
//video quality 1280x720
  self.editor = [UIVideoEditorController new];
  self.editor.videoPath = self.videoPath;
  self.editor.videoMaximumDuration = 180.0;
  #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_5_0
  self.editor.videoQuality =
      UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame1280x720;

#elif __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_4_0
  self.editor.videoQuality =
      UIImagePickerControllerQualityType640x480; // VGA quality
#endif

  self.editor.delegate = self;

  [self.navigationController presentViewController:self.editor
                                          animated:NO
                                        completion:nil];
} else {
  DLog(@"can't edit video at %@", self.videoPath);
}
```

in delegate:

```
- (void)videoEditorController:(UIVideoEditorController *)editor
     didSaveEditedVideoToPath:(NSString *)editedVideoPath {

  [self removeImage:editor.videoPath];

  [editor dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                             completion:^{

                             }];
#if DEBUG
  AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = nil;
  AVURLAsset *asset =
      [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:editedVideoPath]];
  NSArray *videoTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

  CMFormatDescriptionRef formatDescription = NULL;
  NSArray *formatDescriptions = [videoTrack formatDescriptions];
  if ([formatDescriptions count] > 0)
    formatDescription =
        (__bridge CMFormatDescriptionRef)[formatDescriptions objectAtIndex : 0];

  if ([videoTracks count] > 0)
    videoTrack = [videoTracks objectAtIndex:0];

  CGSize trackDimensions = {
      .width = 0.0, .height = 0.0,
  };
  trackDimensions = [videoTrack naturalSize];

  int width = trackDimensions.width;
  int height = trackDimensions.height;
  DLog(@"Resolution = %d X %d", width, height); <-  640x320

#endif

  if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(editedVideoPath)) {

    [self convertVideo:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:editedVideoPath]];

  } else {
    DLog(@"cannot save video on path %@", editedVideoPath);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Quba88 Did you found any solution!

Comment: Sorry no. I used [this controll](https://github.com/andrei200287/SAVideoRangeSlider) and trim a video using AVAssetExportSession. Good luck

Comment: I ended up using same control. Such a shame.

Comment: It's still not working.

Comment: It is now end of 2023 and this is still not working? This cannot really be true. Does nobody have any idea how to solve this?